# Is it possible to read different types of data from one line of a file in JAVA?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readfile, fileinputstream, inputstreamreader

I have a .txt file which I have written values into (with the help of `.writeUTF()` and `.writeInt()` methods). These values are looking like this in the file:

```
StringIntStringIntStringInt
```

There are no symbols inbetween (like " " or commas). Is it possible to still divide the data and somehow read it "out" of the file without converting the `Integers` to `Strings` (I don't even know if this is a real possibility) or putting symbols between the data?

I also have this snippet of my code here, which apparently does not work. I just don't understand the possibilities of reading a file that is "imported" with `BufferedReader`. Is it possible to use something similar to `.writeUTF()` and `.writeInt()` like `.readUTF()` or `.readInt()`? `.readUTF()` does not seem to be an available option.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8"));
String[] subjects = new String[3];
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (!br.readLine().isEmpty()){
    br.readLine();
    subjects[0] = br.read();
    int subjects = br.readInt();
}
return new Timetable(subjects, startingTime);
```

Comment: Which `writeInt` method are you using? If it was in something like `DataOutput`, that's not a text file... that's binary data

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it was a method from DataOutput. How can I use the output of writeInt and writeUTF then?

Comment: You'd use `DataInput`, e.g. with `DataInputStream`. But you mustn't use a `Reader` class to try to read binary data.

Comment: How can I "read" the binary data then? @JonSkeet

Comment: @Brita for binary data reading follow this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/datainputstream_read.htm

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: @SkyWalker Thank you!